# Converting TD Align="center" to CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I am updating legacy code. The code draws a graph in a table cell as part of a weather station output.

Code which works is:

```
<td style="width:33.33%; background-color:#FFFFFF" align="center">
<div id="windchill">small</div>
</td>
```

JavaScript inserts the graph and the resultant object is centered.

I have tried many things but I believe the correct approach should be:

```
<td style="width:33.33%; background-color:#EFEFEF;text-align:center;">
<div id="outsidetemp">small</div>
</td>
```

JavaScript inserts the graph and the resultant object is pulled to the left.

I have tried creating a class in my CSS using `text-align:center;` and using that class for the TD and for the DIV (and both) but the object stays firmly left.

The table and cell definition in CSS is:

```
table {
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    float: left;
/*    table-layout: fixed; */
/*    word-break: break-all;*/ /* debug */
}

td {
    white-space:normal;
//    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    color: #222222;
}
```

There is nothing for TR or DIV.

The only way I can get it to work is to use the deprecated `align="center"` tag on the TD tag. I'd really like to get the page error free.
Any ideas, please?

Comment: have you tried margin-left: auto;

Comment: Thanks - that's a new one that I hadn't tried. I've replaced text align: center with margin-left: auto but it still stays left. I'm beginning to think that the JS function must have something weird in it that's confusing the HTML when it does the document.getelementbyID……InnerHTML = but unfortunately that's not my code and I'm struggling to reverse engineer it.

Comment: You could try to set `text-align` and/or `margin-left` in javascript after the `innerHTML` is changed, but my guess is that because it's using `innerHTML` and not `innerText` it's breaking. That being said I can't find any reason why that would be, just that I've generally been advised to use `innerText` wherever possible. It's probably worth a try though.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this can be applied, but I tested this program on jsfiddle and it seemed to work fine, but changing between `innerHTML` and `innerText` seems to do nothing, so it's likely somewhere else causing the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/mf94a0w2/1/

Comment: Thanks Sam. It looks like I need to invest the time looking at what the function is returning. I have to leave it for a few days now but I'll drop a note when I find out what the problem is. At least you have confirmed that I'm trying to do the right thing!

Answer (score 0):

It was worth digging into the JavaScript which populated the cell.
Embedded in the result was a POSTION:RELATIVE CSS statement. I have simply overridden this with POSTION:STATIC in my shell HTML and all is working correctly - without the ALIGN statement in the TD line.

Thanks for the ideas, and the encouragement to dig deeper. I was tearing out what little hair I had left!

Regards
John